# $\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos \cdots \sin(\cos x)))))))\cdots))))$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I was wondering if there was some easy way to evaluate a repeating pattern of $$\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos x)))$$  for an arbitrary number of $\sin(\cos(\cdots $'s.  I typed it into desmos and notice if I typed in enough it hovered around a value near $.7$ -  Does anyone know the actual value of this number or a finite representation of an arbitrary length string of sines and cosines?

Comment: With arbitrary, do you mean an arbitrary finite composition or infinitely many, i.e. a limit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $$f(x) = \sin \,\left(\cos \,  x \right)$$

You want to find a [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) of $f$, and you suspect from experimentation that it is near $x\approx 0.7$.

This can also be written as the solution to:

$$\arcsin x = \cos x$$

You can see a [graph of $\arcsin$ and $\cos$ and see their intersection here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+y+%3D+arcsin(x)+and+y%3Dcos(x)+from+y%3D-1.5+to+1.5,+x%3D-1.5+to+1.5):

[image]

---

[According to Wolfram | Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+sin(cos+x)), you are correct:

$$x \,\approx \,\boxed{ 0.69482\,}$$

Comment: So I figured that out this morning, but I was hoping for either: 1) a finite representation of the answer, or 2) a proof it is transcendental.

Comment: @skwarerüt As for (1) I put in the approximate decimal solution into the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator here](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/index) but did not find any meaningful results as I increased the number of decimal places that had to match. For (2), do you know whether or not it is transcendental? In general, [it is quite difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Possibly_transcendental_numbers) to prove whether numbers are transcendental ... I probably would not be able to prove or disprove whether this solution is transcendental.

Answer (score 7):

If $y = \sin{(\cos{(\ldots \sin{(\cos{x})})})}$, then we should expect that  $$\sin(\cos(y)) = y,$$

so you can find this value as the zero of $y-\sin(\cos(y)) = 0$.